# Ipad view Alignment

Tags: ipad

In my iPad app, i am supporting only portrait mode except on one screen. I have tab bar at bottom, on click of any tab,it opens a small view of size 320.0 * 600.0, with table view. On selecting any row in small view, a full screen view opens up. Problem is that when i came on full screen view which supports all orientations, next time,my other view especially the small view comes up with frame size of 768 * 1024.
Any sugeestions or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is that you read the frame size while still being in landscape mode. If you are running things in the simulator, it probably jumps back to portrait when you dismiss the full screen? This forces the app back to "portait" mode without triggering the normal "willRotate" functionality, and could possibly mess up your code for keeping track of orientations.

Also keep in mind that most apps needs to support all orientations on the iPad to get accepted, unless you're making e.g. a game which is normally specifically designed for either landscape or portrait.